# How would I install Picasa 3.9?

Tags: software-installation, google-picasa

I've noticed a new release of Picasa (3.9). How would I install it over my current install of Picasa?

Comment: If you have problem with installing:<BR>`env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie6`
change it to <BR>`env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie7`

Comment: some shells don't like the `env`. As I use ZSH on 64 Bit `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie7` worked for me.

Comment: I have just managed to install Picasa 3.9 in my Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64 bit machine. In order to be able to login to my Google account properly, I installed IE8 using the fast track suggested by @desgua with a slight modification:

`sudo apt-get install wine winetricks && cd ~/ && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe && wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe && env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie8 && cp -r ~/.tmp/* ~/.wine/`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**To install Picasa 3.9**

1) Install [wine](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wine) and [winetricks](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/winetricks):
`sudo apt-get install wine winetricks`

2) Download [Picasa 3.9](http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe) from google:
`cd ~/ && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe`

3) Install Picasa with wine:

```
wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe
```

---

**To fix login**

Now you have Picasa 3.9 installed but there is a problem if you want to login to Google to upload some pictures, so to fix it do this:

4) Install Internet Explorer 6:
`env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie6`

You will have to click "Next" and "Accept" in a few windows:

[image]

5) Copy the installation into wine folder:
`cp -r ~/.tmp/* ~/.wine/`

6) Done! Now just open Picasa as any other program:

Open Dash and search for Picasa. Click at the top right corner to login:

[image]

[image]

---

**Notes:**
I) With this method each user will have to run the steps 2 to 5 to get Picasa fully working into his/her user folder. Or ask for he/she to run this once at terminal:

```
 cd ~/ && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe && wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe && env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie6 && cp -r ~/.tmp/* ~/.wine/
```

II) If you are feeling lazy, just paste this at terminal and all the steps above will be done for you (as a user specific installation):

```
 sudo apt-get install wine winetricks && cd ~/ && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe && wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe && env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie6 && cp -r ~/.tmp/* ~/.wine/
```

III) After the step 5, the file "picasa39-setup.exe" can be deleted:
`rm ~/picasa39-setup.exe`

And also the folder "~/.tmp":
`rm ~/.tmp`

IV) To uninstall everything:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine ; sudo apt-get remove --purge winetricks ; sudo apt-get autoremove ; sudo rm /usr/share/applications/Picasa3.desktop ; rm ~/picasa39-setup.exe ; rm -r ~/.tmp ; rm -r ~/.wine ; rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/wine* ; sed -i '/wine/d' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

Comment: The step env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie6 did not work for me: wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string --- If I try only winetricks ie6 then I get: "This package does not work on a 64-bit installation"

Comment: I tried to use this script for installing `google photos auto backup` (which replaced `picasa`) but it didn't work. Im getting "there was a problem authenticating your account". Any chance you know if this can be fixed?

Comment: i think the problem is the 2 step authentication with Google. Installing ie6 with WINE was a workaround but ie6 isn't installing in some setups.

Comment: There is a way to do it with `google photos auto backup` ... basically you just export & import some registry records from a windows installation to Ubuntu. Full instructions here if someone interested: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602555/alternative-for-google-auto-backup-of-image-how-would-i-automate-resize-and/644873#644873

Comment: The Picasa 3.9 binaries are no longer available, but preserved at archive.org at this link here: http://web.archive.org/web/20160823080900/https://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe

Comment: As of 2019 this answer is no longer valid. However, the PlayOnLinux answer works. I just submitted a fix to PlayOnLinux so that the Picasa install will work as long as archive.org is up :)
https://askubuntu.com/a/558055/140858

Comment: @RayB Awesome :-)

Answer (score 12):

If you use Picasa 3.9, you will not be able to connect to your Google account. [According to Google employee Brian Rose, the authentication mechanism was changed to OAuth using an implementation that is currently not compatible with Wine.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=1c3f770cc876aeb9&fid=1c3f770cc876aeb90004b3eaa15d2dfe&hltp=2)

There is [an entry in Wine's AppDB for Picasa 3.9](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25031), and I submitted [a bug report](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29434). As a workaround, install Internet Explorer 6 using [Winetricks](http://winetricks.org). You have to use the upstream Winetricks script, since the one packaged in Ubuntu [has a broken Internet Explorer link](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?versionId=469#Comment-71579).

```
wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine ./winetricks ie6
```

Comment: Great instructions. Instead of IE6.0 work around for google account login. I tried an application specific password using the following link. Worked for me. The link: https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens

Comment: "This package does not work on a 64-bit installation"

Answer (score 9):

[PlayOnLinux supports Picasa 3.9](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1475-Google_Picasa_39.html):

### PlayOnLinux:

> PlayOnLinux is a graphical front-end for the Wine software compatibility layer which allows Linux users to install Windows-based video games, as well as many other applications such as Apple iTunes, Safari, Microsoft Office, Microsoft Internet Explorer.

### Install:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

### Search and do what the wizard says:

[image: League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes]

     <sup>Image from: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu).</sup>

Reference:

- [Google Picasa 3.9 - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1475-Google_Picasa_39.html)