# How do I connect Picasa 3.9 to my online account?

Tags: 11.10, google-picasa

A previous discussion gave excellent instructions on running the latest Picasa version on Ubuntu 11.10 , but I still can't get an effective connection between the desktop application and my online account.

[Existing instructions for installation and config of connection between Picasa desktop and server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9)

I tried the Winetricks approach, but my netbook perhaps does not have the grunt to process all the information at once. It requested I instal Gecko the first time I tried to connect with my Picasa account, but then just hangs. Having installed Winetricks, how may I uninstal it and use the application specific password approach you mention? Thanks for your assistance

Comment: please mark it as answered

Answer (score 2):

read the instructions here ...

[Install Picasa 3.9 in linux](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-picasa-39-in-linux-and-fix.html)