# Does the Picasa 3.9 wine/winetricks/ie6 fix leave any vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, google-picasa, ie

I recently added Picasa 3.9 to my Ubuntu 11.10 machine using the technique from this askUbuntu question: [How would I install Picasa 3.9?](https://askubuntu.com/q/86452/40021)

But I'm wondering:  does adding IE 6.0 (or Wine or Winetricks) leave my system vulnerable in any way?  Since the IE 6.0 was added to allow Picasa 3.9 login, I'm concerned about entering my Google account credentials, should I be?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought Google dropped support for IE6 back in 2010.

Comment: No, adding IE6 allows one to log into one's Google account in Picasa 3.9 using wine in Linux. Sorry for all the fancy sounding "one"s. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding Wine of Winetricks does not make your system vulnerable.

However, applications which run in Wine are vulnerable as if they were on Windows, in the sense that if you for example run IE6, it is suceptable to vulnerabilities just as if it were running on Windows. To make it more secure, you can use a Firewall, and only use it to login the one time that is needed. Beyond this point, you should have no worries about vulnerabilities.