# Repo to install Picasa

Tags: google-picasa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I install Picasa 3.9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9)

Is there any repo to install Picasa from ?

The one listed in this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9) doesn't seem to be working anymore, or at least not for 12.04.

Thanks!

Comment: Picasa 3.9 can't run native on Linux. Only via Wine. And Google has stopped Picasa support since April 20th of this year. So I adice you to find another photomanager

Comment: I have added a bounty to get a new or updated answer for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Picasa** is being officially dropped for Linux, here

http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/spring-cleaning-in-spring.html

> We launched a WINE-based version of Picasa for Linux in 2006 as a
>   Google Labs project. As we continue to enhance Picasa, it has become
>   difficult to maintain parity on the Linux version. So today, we’re
>   **deprecating Picasa for Linux** and **will not be maintaining it moving
>   forward.** Users who have downloaded and installed older versions of
>   Picasa for Linux can continue to use them, though we won’t be making
>   any further updates.

The Linux Picasa Homepage doesn't exists anymore.

Though you can still use it using wine.