# Is there a native Picasa version for Linux? How can I install it?

Tags: package-management, google-picasa

How can I install Google Picasa 3.9 or whatever the latest version is.

I don't want the Wine version, I want the native Linux version.

I'm trying to avoid using programs via Wine because it is very buggy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is and there never was a *native Picasa for Linux* version.**

What Google always did  was to wrap Picasa in a nice package containing Picasa and a custom version of Wine.

If you want to install Picasa in Linux it always has to use Wine, either installed by you or using the packages from Google that contain Wine. In the end its your choice and will lead to the same.

Because the Linux installation is just a Wine wrapper with the Windows binaries, Google has discontinued the support for Linux and the last available package in their repositories is for Ubuntu 11.10, version 3.0.

Google explains that if a Linux user needs to use Picasa he can use the Wine version installed in Ubuntu to run the Windows binaries, making no sense to invest time developing something extra.

Google wrong on their blog on April 20, 2012:

> "(...)today, we’re deprecating Picasa for Linux and will not be maintaining it moving forward.”
>   <sub>([source](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/spring-cleaning-in-spring.html))</sub>

They also explain that maintaining the package for Linux is becoming harder since and that is costing them time compared with Windows releases.

For instruction on how to install Picasa 3.9 in your system please have a look at

- [How would I install Picasa 3.9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9)

There are guides on that post that will help install Picasa 3.9 in your system, either by installing Wine and then Picasa with it, or by updating the Google package from version 3.0 to version 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

This will install picasa 3.0, and not 3.9

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/pool/non-free/p/picasa/picasa_3.0-current_i386.deb
```

and then run

```
sudo dpkg -i picasa_3.0-current_i386.deb
```

I just tried it on 12.04 64, and it worked fine.  it will ask you to install othe libs if you are on **64bit system**, just answer yes, and it will install automatically.  If not just run this command

```
sudo apt-get install lib32nss-mdns
```

and it works fine.

> Picasa for Linux was never really the most sincere of ports. It used a
>   self-contained WINE installer to run under Linux, and whilst for the
>   most part this didn’t impact on its usability there was always a
>   definite lull in its system integration.

Now using Shotwell. Here we have organization, editing and online integration all in one happy package. If there are three sites people share photos on, it’s Facebook, Flickr and Picasa. Happily Shotwell can upload photos to all three. Doing this couldn’t be easier: just highlight the photos you want to upload, then click “Publish.” You can then sign into any of those accounts and upload the photos.  Shotwell in included by default in Ubuntu.

Source: [omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/google-officially-drop-picasa-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picassa as a web based application without installing anything, have a look at this link :
[Picassa Web](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en_US&continue=https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/login?continue=https%253A%252F%252Fpicasaweb.google.com%252Fhome&service=lh2&ltmpl=gp&passive=true)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to install picasa using wine you can always install virtualbox, fire up a windows OS/machine and use picasa - I do this all the time

Comment: thats still emulation, not native. taht only makes things harder

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't install Picasa 3.9 without wine. I store Picasa 3.8 in my PC. And installed it besides Picasa 3.9 (using Wine).

And I work with Picasa 3.9 by using Wine and it works good.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Wine and Winetricks. For Ubuntu, use the commands below:

sudo apt-get install wine winetricks

For older Ubuntu versions (like 10.04) which don't have Winetricks available in the repositories or other Linux distributions, install Winetricks using the following commands:

cd
wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks
sudo mv winetricks /usr/local/bin/
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/winetricks

1. Install Picasa 3.9:

cd && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe
wine picasa39-setup.exe

1. To be able to login to your Google account using Picasa 3.9, you must install Internet Explorer 6 via Winetricks by running the following command:

winetricks ie6

If you get an error (link not found) and the Internet Explorer 6 setup doesn't start, you can manually download Internet Explorer 6 from HERE (click the "Internet Explorer 6 (full)" link). Then, place the downloaded "ie60.exe" file under the ~/.cache/winetricks/ie6/ folder (".cache" is a hidden folder in your home directory so press CTRL + H to see it). And finally, run:

winetricks ie6

Now the Internet Explorer setup should start:

& this should be helpful 
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-picasa-39-in-linux-and-fix.html
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/google-stops-supporting-picasa-for.html