# Picasa packages for Ubuntu are no longer available

Tags: 64-bit, picasa

While trying to install Picasa for Ubuntu, the following errors occurred:

```
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/pool/non-free/p/picasa/picasa_3.0-current_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i picasa_3.0-current_amd64.deb

--2012-08-30 17:41:36--  http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/pool/non-free/p/picasa/picasa_3.0-current_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 74.125.237.128, 74.125.237.142, 74.125.237.136, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|74.125.237.128|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-08-30 17:41:36 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because Picasa is no longer distributed for Linux. Complain to google about that :-(

Alternatively, you can install Picasa for Windows using Wine. You can find instructions for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9). I don't mean the first answer (which tells you to use ubuntu repositories that are no longer available), but the one with the title "To install Picasa 3.9" further down the page.