# Ubuntu 12.10 Picasa installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, picasa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

I've used script from [How would I install Picasa 3.9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9):
1) Install wine and winetricks:
`sudo apt-get install wine winetricks`

and

``` sudo apt-get install wine winetricks && cd ~/ && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa``/picasa39-setup.exe && wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe && env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.tmp winetricks ie6 && cp -r ~/.tmp/* ~/.wine/ ```

but stack on
 Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer ├─────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │
 │ TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA
 │
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE
 │
 │ IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement
 │ ("EULA") is a legal agreement between you (either an individual or a
 │ single entity) and Microsoft Corporation for the Microsoft software
 │ accompanying this EULA, which includes computer software and may include
 │ associated media, printed materials, and "on-line" or electronic
 │ documentation ("SOFTWARE PRODUCT" or "SOFTWARE"). By exercising your
 │ rights to make and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, you agree to be
 │ bound by the terms of this EULA. If you do not agree to the terms of
 │ this EULA, you may not use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.
 │
 │
 │                                  
 │                                                                           │
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

it has happen under both scripts dont move nowhere. Does somebody know how to handle this issue?
Thanks in advance 
Nick

Comment: It is much easy to close case rather than refer to answer. After that approach I have not big wish to communicate.