# How can I find all the images on my system?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management

Is there something I can use to find all the pictures on my system including external HD so that I can copy them all into one folder?

Comment: Are you interested in a bash script that might do this for you ?

Comment: I'd be interested in a bash shell script or preferably a "file explorer" feature that would let me boot up from Ubuntu 16 USB stick and find all images on the Windows partition, so that I can back them up. Focus is on finding (rather than backup), to make sure that I don't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can install picasa to gather all pictures at one spot.
You can install picasa from the answer of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9)

Comment: is there not anything native to ubuntu???? I mean why do I want to run exsploder in wine???