# Alternative for Google+ auto backup of image... how would I automate resize and transfer?

Tags: sync, image-processing, google-picasa

I get by with Linux but I'm by no means a guru, so please be nice :)

On my other devices (Android, Windows) I use Picasa and its Auto Backup feature to automatically resize and upload to my Google drive.  Honestly, I don't really know how it works, it just works.  I back up my photos full size to my Ubuntu server locally and from there to Crash Plan so this isn't about data security, it is specifically for Google+ sharing and the "neat" features they have.  Because they allow unlimited photos for anything < 2048*2048 I want to resize.

So how can I:

1. resize
2. upload
3. stay synced

Preferably from the command line, as it is a headless server.

Oh, I should probably say this:  I did just add my network folder containing all those folders into my Windows machine's Picasa... and that's working - sort of.  Problem #1 is that it says its going to take 42 days to complete.  The bigger problem, however, is that it is really trashing my Internet connection.  I'm not sure why.  I did a test with local photos and it doesn't affect my connection at all, but my VOIP was dying periodically and I narrowed it down to it being whenever the server was being accessed by Picasa for a photo.  Anyway, for long term success I think I'd like to do the above rather than using Picasa for this task.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to install `Google photos auto backup` on Ubuntu (taken from [here on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/37ptsw/any_got_the_new_google_photos_backup_desktop/), worked for me...)

1. Install google photos auto backup on Windows machine (may be a virtual PC or an ordinary PC)
2. Start > Run > regedit
3. go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Picasa\Picasa2\Preferences
4. Then on Menu > registry > export registry file.
   It should look something like this:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Picasa\Picasa2\Preferences]
   "GoogleOAuth"=hex:xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,\      xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx
   "GoogleOAuthEmail"="youremail@gmail.com"
   "GoogleOAuthServices"="mail,lh2,cp,cp.manager,mailrelay,plus.stream.write,    plus.circles.read,plus.profiles.read,plus.me,plus.media.upload,plus.media.    readonly,plus.settings,youtube,"
   "GoogleOAuthVersion"=dword:00000005
   ```
5. Install playOnLinux. Go to configure, create a new 32-bit Windows virtual drive, call it GooglePhotosBackup. Select the new virtual drive. In wine tab > task manager > new task, select the [gpautobackup_setup.exe](https://dl.google.com/dl/picasa/gpautobackup_setup.exe) file you've downloaded from google and install google auto backup.
6. Select the new virtual drive again > registry editor , then on menu > registry > import registry file > import the registry file you created earlier.
7. General tab > *make a new shortcut from this virtual drive* button and select *google photos backup.exe*.

Finally, run the application and you should be logged in!

Comment: Is there no solution with higher WAF?

Comment: Can this be executed from a cron task?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use Windows version of Google Photos Backup inside a prebuilt VM from [modern.ie](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) VM using Virtual Box. I use Shared-Folders to make the Pictures visible to Windows. Simple and no hacking of registries required.