# Set picassa photo viewer as default app for image

Tags: wine, photo-management, picasa

I just installed Picasa in my Ubuntu 14.04 using Wine following this [How would I install Picasa 3.9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9) until step 3 cause i don't want to connect to my Picasa account. I want just to use Picasa photo viewer. So, i want to make Picasa image viewer as my default image viewer. I tried this in the Default applications, but I can't find an entry for Picasa there. How can I make Picasa my default image viewer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `mimeopen`, in a terminal go to the folder where you have some pictures with extensions, you should do it for every extension. Suppose for picture named image.jpg. Run the command:

```
mimeopen -d image.jpg
```

You will get a popup menu, where you can see some options, here is sample of my apps:

```
$ minemimeopen -d e.jpg 
Please choose a default application for files of type image/jpeg

    1) Wine Internet Explorer  (wine-extension-jpe)
    2) Wine Internet Explorer  (wine-extension-jfif)
    3) gThumb  (gthumb)
    4) Pinta  (pinta)
    5) Image Viewer  (gpicview)
    6) Shutter  (shutter)
    7) Firefox Web Browser  (firefox)
    8) Shotwell Viewer  (shotwell-viewer)
    9) GIMP Image Editor  (gimp)
    10) Other...
```

AS you can notice you could see some wine apps so if you find picasa choose it, else choose other(10) and type the command that runs your picasa. It looks like

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/myapps/foo.exe
```