# How to install picasa on ubuntu using winetricks?

Tags: 16.04, wine, winetricks, picasa

I have installed wintricks & also followed the guidelines of this question's => **[Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9)**. 
But I'm getting this problem => (Check the print screen I have shared below)

[image: picasa_ubuntu printscreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`404 NOT FOUND` on your download of the Picasa installer means that the installer is *not* present at the requested URL.

This is less an Ubuntu issue, and more an issue of Picasa/Google's side.

HOWEVER, according to https://picasa.google.com/:

> **Moving on from Picasa**
>   We’ve decided to retire Picasa in order to focus on a single photo service in Google Photos – a new, smarter photo app that works seamlessly across mobile and the web.

Therefore, **you are no longer able to get Picasa** from Google, and instead need to use the Google Photos system, which has no local application for it.  (Which means that you *cannot* install Picasa anymore anywhere)